# Matlab conditional for if a vector is the same as any vector in a cell

Tags: performance, matlab, conditional-statements

I have a vector of size 1x3, and I want to execute a command only if this vector has never been seen before. How can I do this?

The reason is because I have a computationally expensive function that takes a long time to compute, and I need to evaluate it many times. Therefore, I don't want to re-evaluate it if I have already done it before.

Here is a minimal working example of my attempt:

```
for j=1:999

    x=[randi([0 30]), randi([0 30]), randi([0 30])];   %//in my actual function these values are selected using a genetic algorithm. 

    x(x == 0) = [];       %//delete all zero values. This is so x can be different sizes and does not contain any zeros.

    xHistory{j}=x;

    if x~=xHistory(:,:)        %//if x has never been seen before then...

        y=ExpensiveFunction(x);            %//This function takes a huge amount of time to compute

        yHistory(j)=y;

    else                       %//if it has been seen before get the same value as last time

    y=yHistory(j);

    end


end
```

My problem is with the conditional statement:

```
if x~=xHistory(:,:)        %//if x has never been seen before then...
```

I get the error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'ne' for input arguments of
type 'cell'.
```

I expected this, I just tried this conditional because I don't know how to write the one I actually need. It needs to execute only if there is no vector 'x' in any of cell 'xHistory'.

Also the statement that returns the value for the already solved `x` combinations does not return the correct value.

```
yHistory(j)=y;
```

This will just return the value that `x` gave `y` on the `j`th iteration. I need it to give the value that `x` gave `y` on the iteration that this same `x` was used. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this instead for comparison - `isequal(x,xHistory{:})` or `~isequal(x,xHistory{:})` for your case.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this didn't work, the `ExpensiveFunction` will execute even if it has seen the inputs before.

Comment: if all are `1x3` vectors, consider storing them in a `Nx3` matrix and then use `ismember`. `Cells` are making things difficult unnecessarily, I feel.

Comment: @Divakar I tested it to by forcing `x` to be `[1 2 3]`, and making `ExpensiveFunction` open a figure if it runs. I ran the script twice and the figure opened both times.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: Ah of course. This makes sense, thanks! I got confused because I've had to save a matrix history in a cell in a past project before. A matrix should work better for this though. I'll try that now and post if it helps.

Comment: I showed how to do it using cells. Using matrix, you should be able to do it.

Comment: the test for the if statement could be `ismember(x,vertcat(xHistory{:}),'rows')` however as mentioned above if applicable a Nx3 matrix would make things easier (and probably faster) allowing `ismember(x,xHistory,'rows')` to be used...

Comment: Made an edit as I have noticed another flaw in my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your **x** only ever contain integers from 0 through to 30 for each of the three dimensions?  If so, you could consider creating two 3D matrices:

```
xHasBeenSolved = logical(zeros(31,31,31));  % soln already found for x
xSolution      = zeros(31,31,31);           % the solution from expensive func
```

Just prior to evaluating your vector **x**, check to see if has already been solved:

```
if xHasBeenSolved(x(1)+1,x(2)+1,x(3)+1)
   % true so grab the previously found solution
   y = xSolution(x(1)+1,x(2)+1,x(3)+1);
else
   % false so evaluate for x
   y = ExpensiveFunction(x);

   % flag that this solution has been solved and save it
   xHasBeenSolved(x(1)+1,x(2)+1,x(3)+1) = true; 
   xSolution(x(1)+1,x(2)+1,x(3)+1)      = y;
end
```

Since your values in **x** begin at zero, the +1 is necessary for each access into either 3D matrix.  Hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, `x` only contains integers from 0 through 30. I'll try this or one of the other solutions after I've had my tea.

Comment: I implemented this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I forgot that the size of `x` isn't always `1x3` as it is in the question. It can also be `1x2` or `1x1`. I really feel like there must be an easier way to do this, I just can't work it out.

Comment: I now remember why I originally used cells to store xHistory.

Comment: But how does ExpensiveFunction treat an input that is 1x1, 1x2 and 1x3?  Does it use default values for the "missing" inputs?  For example, if the input is [1 2 3], what does the code do differently when the input is just [1]?

Comment: The ExpensiveFunction uses `feedforwardnet(x)`, then trains it on training data, and then returns the performance when tested on testing data. `feedforwardnet` is a built in Matlab function, and I assume it uses `varargin` so it can handle inputs of different sizes. So when `x` is [1 2 3] the ExpensiveFunction will train a neural network with 1 neuron in the first layer, 2 in the second, and 3 in the third. It will then return the performance of this net (a scalar number). When `x` is just [1], the ExpensiveFunction will train a neural network with just 1 neuron in its 1 only layer.

Comment: Hmmm…reading the documentation on that function indicates that this vector contains the sizes of one or more hidden layers.  If that is true, then wouldn't [1] be equivalent to [1 0] and [1 0 0]? i.e. if no layer is passed, is this the same as a hidden layer of size 0?  I almost think that it would be - so if you have solved for [1 0 0] then you have (by default) solved for [1 0] and [1] as well…and so you may be able to use the same xHasBeenSolved matrix from above.

Comment: Yes, but passing [1 0 0] returns an error. To solve this I have put `x(x == 0) = [];` after the part that generates the `x` value (the `randi` bit in my question, but the genetic algorithm in the real thing). This has the effect that `x` can be a vector from size `1x1` to `1x3` with no zeros, and so the `feedforwardnet` function is happy. I'm going to add this to my minimal example in the question as I guess it is important.

Comment: But that's good!  So if your above function gets passed the 1x1 vector, then just look at **xHasBeenSolved(x(1)+1,1,1)** to see if the ExpensiveFunction has already evaluated this.  Same for a 1x2, just check **xHasBeenSolved(x(1)+1,x(2)+1,1)** and that should be sufficient.  (Unless I've missed something?)

Comment: The problem is that when x is size `1x1` or `1x2` it can't find x(2) and/or x(3) when it checks `if xHasBeenSolved(x(1)+1,x(2)+1,x(3)+1)`. The error matlab returns is: `Attempted to access x(3); index out of bounds because numel(x)=2.`

Comment: For sure, but you can write code to get around that - just use another vector to "get into" the **xHasBeenSolved** and **xSolution** matrices: `xp=zeros(3,1);xp(1:length(x))=x;` and then `xHasBeenSolved(xp(1)+1,xp(2)+1,xp(3)+1)` should work fine because **xp** will always be of length 3...

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! This is part of my dissertation due in next week, and i'm incredibly stressed. I cant tell you grateful I am!

Comment: Glad to have been able to help!

Answer (score 1):

If all are `1x3` vectors, consider storing them in a `Nx3` matrix and then use `ismember`. `Cells` are making things difficult unnecessarily, I feel.

If you want to use cell, you can use, `~any(cellfun(@(y) isequal(y,x), xHistory))` in place of `x~=xHistory(:,:)`.

Comment: I tried `~any(cellfun(@(y) isequal(y,x), xHistory))` in place of `x~=xHistory(:,:)`. And it stopped `ExpensiveFunction` from running, but it always returns y=0. (This might be because I predefined the y history cell full zeros).

Comment: I think it always returns zero because the condition: `x~=xHistory(:,:) ` is never satisfied. `xHistory` always has `x`. See this line in your code: `xHistory{j}=x;`. If I remove that line and run the code, it runs the expensive function (obviously filling up `xHistory` before with random numbers).